# Android RecyclerView does not load firebase items until application restart

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a RecyclerView, which acts weird. I'm attaching it to data from a firebase database and there are no errors or crashses.

I need to close the application compeletely and reopen it **only one time** after installing it and log in with an account, and then it will start loading (the RecyclerView is inside a SwipeRefreshLayout).

Actions and events step-by-step:

1. I install the app.
2. Log in with existing account.
3. The RecyclerView gets the current data.
4. When swipeing down with SwipeRefreshLayout, the RecyclerView doesn't load any data.
5. After i close the application (pressing mainmenu on the phone and closing the app) and reopen it, the problem disappears and the SwipeRefreshLayout works perfectly.
6. When logging in with another account (for the first time), problem starts allover again.

I dont even know which code is doing that.

Comment: you could try loading your data in your onResume method

Comment: Could you please share the code, which handels the data with us, so we can understand your problem better?

Comment: i dont even know which code to share , actually the recycler is not loading when new use is signed in , but , it will load if the user is resumed the activity , i copied all the resume activity intents and pasted in the on start and still same .

Comment: @AmerAnajjem Did you write the code yourself or did you copy / download it? If you got it from a website, please link your source, so we know what your code does. This seems like a mistake in the code and so we can't help you without seeing it. **Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: the codes is copied , but i did regulate it too much to fits my recuirments , any way i am in the middle of finding the reason , looks like there is a login presenter which will check if you have an account or not , and , looks like it does not acts same when the account is at first use or if it is in the second use , what i need is :- ether make the program do same as when the login is not first time which makes all the functions works , or i go with find a way to make the program close and reload without losing the user interface .

Answer (score 0):

Apply onchildeventlistener on database reference